# Can’t get push notifications in Android to work using ngCordova

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm having a tough time getting push notifications (using the ngCordova plugin) to work. I have followed their sample code exactly as is documented on the site: http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/pushNotifications/

(the only difference is that I don't have a deviceready listener, instead, my code is inside the ionicPlatform.ready listener.)

Here is my code:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $rootScope, $state, $cordovaPush) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    var config = {
      "senderID": "myID100001000"
    };

    $cordovaPush.register(config).then(function(result) {
      alert(result);
    }, function(err) {
      alert(err);
    })      
  }); 

  $rootScope.$on('$cordovaPush:notificationReceived', function(event, notification) {
    switch(notification.event) {
      case 'registered':
        if (notification.regid.length > 0 ) {
          alert('registration ID = ' + notification.regid);
        }
        break;

      default:
        alert('An unknown GCM event has occurred');
        break;
    }
  });  
})
```

When my app starts I do get the "OK" alert, so I know it successfully goes through the $cordovaPush.register call. However, I was expecting to get a "registered" notification event, right after, but I never get notified.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Im having the exact same problem. Were you able to fix it ?

Comment: @casper123 yes, I fixed it.  The problem was that I was using the project id instead of the project number. This is not well documented.  Also, in the version of cordova I was using, the event was called pustNotificationReceived and not $cordovaPush:notificationReceived, so I needed to rename that.

Comment: Hi, Prabhu. I'm facing exactly the same problem that you had. I've checked my senderID and I'm pretty sure that my configuration is right. But still not working. I also don't have any ngCordova issue. Any suggestion?

Comment: @Prabhu I only found project id, no project number. How to fix it?

Comment: @casper123 Were you fix this issue?

Comment: @casper123 I finally fix the problem using ngCordova plugin. See my question and my answer for your reference here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28468571/ionic-framework-pushplugin-onnotificationgmc-is-not-fired-and-cannot-obtain-reg/28491884?noredirect=1#comment45313966_28491884

Comment: @Prabhu's comment above on the naming of receive event, did the trick for me. It is infact pushNotificationReceived. There is a typo in Prabhu's comment above.

Answer (score 8):

The solution is in the comments but this needs a proper answer.

First of all, the `register` callback always returns `OK` as long as you pass a `senderID`, but if the `$cordovaPush:notificationReceived` event is never called (it may take a few seconds), this ID is probably wrong.

You **must** use the **Project Number**, not the Project ID.

To get the number, go to the [API Console](https://console.developers.google.com/), select the project and you'll be on the *Overview* page. On top of this page, you'll see something like this:

```
Project ID: your-project-id        Project Number: 0123456789
```

Just copy and use the project number and everything should work.

Answer (score 1):

I have suffered with this a lot and I have found out, that there are in fact two versions of the cordova push plugin currently:

- https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin (deprecated)
- https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push (new one)

Both are supported by ngCordova, but only the deprecated version is documented.

The deprecated version is **$cordovaPush**
and the newer one is **$cordovaPushV5**, and they have completely different methods.

For me the problem was that I downloaded the cordova-plugin-push and tried to implement it with the old documentation on ngCordova site.

The code is:

```js
 /*
         * Non deprecated version of Push notification events
         */
        function registerV5() {

            $ionicLoading.show({
                template: '<ion-spinner></ion-spinner>'
            });

            if (ionic.Platform.is('browser')) {
                alert("You are running on broswer, please switch to your device. Otherwise you won't get notifications");
                $ionicLoading.hide();
                return;
            }

            /**
             * Configuration doc:
             * https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/API.md#pushnotificationinitoptions
             */
            var GCM_PROJECT_ID = 'xxxxxx';

            $cordovaPushV5.initialize({
                "android": {
                    "clearNotifications": false,
                    "senderID" : GCM_PROJECT_ID
                }
            });

            $cordovaPushV5.register().then(function (deviceToken) {
                console.log("Successfully registered", deviceToken);

                $scope.data.deviceToken = deviceToken;

                // Below code required to configure $cordovaPushV5 notifications emitter. 
                // Don't pass function it's not handler.
                $cordovaPushV5.onNotification();
                $cordovaPushV5.onError();

                $ionicLoading.hide();
            }, function (error) {
                console.log("Failed to registered");
                console.log("error object : ", error);
                $ionicLoading.hide();
            });
        }

        $rootScope.$on('$cordovaPushV5:notificationReceived', function(event, data) {
            console.log("notification received");
            console.log("data object: ", data);

            var foreground = data.additionalData.foreground || false;
            var threadID = data.additionalData.payload.threadID || '';
            var group = data.additionalData.payload.group || false;

            if (foreground) {
                // Do something if the app is in foreground while receiving to push - handle in app push handling
                console.log('Receive notification in foreground');
            } else {
                // Handle push messages while app is in background or not started
                console.log('Receive notification in background');
                // Open FB messanger app when user clicks notification UI when app is in background.
                if (typeof data.additionalData.coldstart != "undefined" && data.additionalData.coldstart == false)
                    if (!group)
                        // Open FB Messenger of specific user chat window
                        window.open('fb-messenger://user/' + threadID, '_system', 'location=no');
                    else
                        // Open FB Messenger of specific group chat window
                        window.open('fb-messenger://groupthreadfbid/' + threadID, '_system', 'location=no');                
            }
        });

        $rootScope.$on('$cordovaPushV5:errorOccurred', function(event, error) {
            console.log("notification error occured");
            console.log("event object: ", event);
            console.log("error object: ", error);
        });
```

More on this github article: https://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova/issues/1125 (code from here) and in this article: https://github.com/yafraorg/yafra/wiki/Blog-Ionic-PushV5